# How does Vax from Critical Role get three attacks per round?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, critical-role-show

I am getting ready to play D&D for the first time and really excited! I have been watching Critical Role to learn a little more. I am going to be playing a rogue and on Critical Role Vax often attacks with 3 daggers. When you're duel wielding do both attacks count as one then using a bonus action to get to third? It has been confusing me.

Comment: This isn't really an answer but as an avid watcher of critical-role myself, Matt Mercer, their DM, has numerous houserules that let his players do stuff so that they can maximimze their fun. Case in point, Trinket the bear is not a legal ranger companion, a Bard should not be able to inspire himself, oh, and... Gunslinger. He's the kind of DM who vetoes all the rules to favor the Rule of Cool/Fun.

Comment: @daze413 He is living up to the spirit of the game, whether or not he adheres to the letter of any and all rules.  I consider that laudable.

Comment: I will say that gunslinger rules are now part of the d&d online.

Answer (score 35):

You're rightly confused — you don't normally get three attacks per round like that. By itself, fighting with two weapons gives you at most *two* attacks — one from the normal Attack Action and one from a Bonus Action with the off-hand weapon.

Vax therefore has something else going on that is allowing that third attack. From the [Critical Role Wiki's FAQ](http://criticalrole.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ):

> #### How does Vax get 3 attacks per round?
>
> He dual wields daggers for 2 attacks and has a custom magic item brought over from Pathfinder called *boots of haste* which function like the spell.

So Vax is making the first two attacks according to the normal rules for Two-Weapon Fighting (on page 195 of the PHB), and then making a third via the extra Action granted by D&D 5e's version of the spell *haste* (p. 250).

Comment: In a recent episode where Liam actually DMs, Travis asks him if he can attack three times "like the famous rogue, Vax: Dagger dagger dagger.", Liam replies that Travis would need the Boots of Haste, and the Dual Wielder feat. This still needs to be confirmed, however, as you really don't need Dual Wielder to two-weapon fight with daggers, and it might just be a houserule Matt uses to allow the triple dagger throw.

Comment: Th Dual Wielder feat is required to make the triple-attack so effective, though: without it, the bonus-action attack made with the offhand weapon doesn't add your Strength or dex bonus to the attack roll.

Comment: @anaximander That's not what Dual Wielder, the feat, does. You are thinking about Two-Weapon Fighting, the feature.

Comment: @daze413 Indeed I am. I get those two mixed up all the time.

Comment: I would be very curious to see how often he spent the bonus action on something else before Dagger Dagger Daggering out of habit and Matt didn't notice.  I don't recall a time he just Dagger Daggered without the Boots of Haste explicitly not being active.